# SMTP server correct email routing

Tags: email, routes, smtp

I'm trying to implement a SMTP server at the moment and I've question regarding the routing...
Imagine, a client (foo@bar.com) sends a mail to foo1@bar1.com, foo2@bar2.com and foo3@bar3.com.
What happens when the SMTP server sees the message? Now, I'm not sure if the following sequence is correct:

1. The SMTP server will put the mail into the outbox of foo@bar.com
2. For each recipient (except foo@bar.com) in the envelope, the SMTP server will do:

   1. Retrieve the MX record
   2. Connect to the SMTP server determined by the MX record
   3. Send HELO/EHLO command
   4. Send MAIL FROM command (foo@bar.com)
   5. Send RCPT TO command (e.g. foo1@bar1.com)
   6. Send DATA command
   7. Send QUIT command

Are these steps correct? For me it makes sense that the SMTP of the sender processes all the communication, but I've found some pages (e.g. https://www.msxfaq.de/internet/envelope.htm) where a mail server only forwards the message to the next SMTP server and each SMTP server removes one recipient from envelop's rcpt-to list, e.g.

[image]

So, what's correct...?

1. Sender's SMTP handles all the routing
2. Sender's SMTP removes one recipient (in this case foo@bar.com) and then forwards the message to the next SMTP server

Comment: IMHO you better ask here [sf]

Answer (score 0):

The steps you listed are basically correct.

The complexity arises when you compose an email and try to send it to a lot of different domains, e.g. steve@apple.com, woz@apple.com, and bill@microsoft.com.

In this case, the server must do MX lookups on each one of these domains and split the email.  Steve and Woz are both at the same domain, so the server can send an email with those two recipients to the MX record for apple.com.  The server must open a separate connection to the MX record for microsoft.com and attempt to send the email to Bill over that connection.